# Get current location with background service Android

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to get the user's locations in real time using service. The problem happens when I try to do this below Android 8.0 because of the foreground service, I looked for several ways to do this but I didn't find any that work below Android 8.0.

Code that i used:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.btn_start_tracking)
    Button btnStartTracking;

    @BindView(R.id.btn_stop_tracking)
    Button btnStopTracking;

    @BindView(R.id.txt_status)
    TextView txtStatus;

    public BackgroundService gpsService;
    public boolean mTracking = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplication(), BackgroundService.class);
        this.getApplication().startService(intent);
        this.getApplication().startForegroundService(intent);
        this.getApplication().bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_start_tracking)
    public void startLocationButtonClick() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        gpsService.startTracking();
                        mTracking = true;
                        toggleButtons();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            openSettings();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_stop_tracking)
    public void stopLocationButtonClick() {
        mTracking = false;
        gpsService.stopTracking();
        toggleButtons();
    }

    private void toggleButtons() {
        btnStartTracking.setEnabled(!mTracking);
        btnStopTracking.setEnabled(mTracking);
        txtStatus.setText( (mTracking) ? "TRACKING" : "GPS Ready" );
    }

    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction( Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            String name = className.getClassName();
            if (name.endsWith("BackgroundService")) {
                gpsService = ((BackgroundService.LocationServiceBinder) service).getService();
                btnStartTracking.setEnabled(true);
                txtStatus.setText("GPS Ready");
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            if (className.getClassName().equals("BackgroundService")) {
                gpsService = null;
            }
        }
    };

}

Background service class

    public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private final LocationServiceBinder binder = new LocationServiceBinder();
    private final String TAG = "BackgroundService";
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 500;
    private final int LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        private Location lastLocation = null;
        private final String TAG = "LocationListener";
        private Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            Log.i(TAG, "LocationChanged: "+location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        startForeground(12345678, getNotification());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    public void startTracking() {
        initializeLocationManager();
        mLocationListener = new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            // Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void stopTracking() {
        this.onDestroy();
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel_01", "My Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "channel_01").setAutoCancel(true);
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    public class LocationServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public BackgroundService getService() {
            return BackgroundService.this;
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ac.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".maps"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".BackgroundService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```